# Corrupted JSON encoding?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm sending a JSON object of the same class from a servlet to an applet, but
all strings variables in this class are missing some characters like: 'ą', 'ę', 'ś', 'ń', 'ł'.
However, 'ó' is displayed normally (?). For example: 
"Zaznacz prawid**?**ow**?** operacj**?** por**ó**wnywania dw**ó**ch zmiennych typu"

**Solution**
I wish I could explain it more thoroughly, but as Henry noticed, it's IDE causing this issue. I solved it using farmer1992's class from the google ticket. It prints escaped unicode characters (\u...) - the only way my applet could encode characters correctly. Also I have to restart NetBeans IDE from time to time to force the Tomcat servlet to work correctly (I have no idea why :) ).

Servlet code (updated with solution):

```
//begin of the servlet code extract
public void sendToApplet(HttpServletResponse response, String path) throws IOException
{
    TestServlet x = new TestServlet();
    x.load(path);

    String json = new Gson().toJson(x);
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    //out.print(json);
    //out.flush();
    GhettoAsciiWriter out2 = new GhettoAsciiWriter(out);
    out2.write(json);
    out2.flush();

}
//end of the servlet code extract
```

Applet code:

```
//begin of the applet code extract
public void retrieveFromServlet(String path) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    String encoder = URLEncoder.encode(path, "UTF-8");
    URL urlServlet = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ProjektServlet?action=" + encoder);
    URLConnection connection = urlServlet.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String json = br.readLine();
    Test y = new Gson().fromJson(json, Test.class);
    inputStream.close();
}
//end of the applet code extract
```

Comment: What's encoded ? If it contains strings, are you sure there are proper ly read ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those chars should encode in \uxxxx form

you can see this ticket 
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=388#c4

Comment: This ticket doesn't mean Gson can't handle Unicode chars. I often use build UTF-8 encoded JSON with Gson, as is allowed by the norm, without problem.

Comment: I used this class to print JSON. Tested it in a browser - the result is the same as above: `Zaznacz prawid\u0142ow\u0105 operacj\u0119 por\u00f3wnywania dw\u00f3ch zmiennych typu`... Slowly loosing my patience with this...

Comment: @BMC chars like \u0142ow are safe to be decoded with gson if you cant see check your font settings

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

the platform character encoding will be used (which may or may not be UTF-8). Try to set the encoding explicitly with

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Didn't help. Getting now '?' on a black background instead of 'ó'.

Comment: Can you check if the value of `json` in the applet is ok or already corrupted? The writing and reading code seems to be ok now.

Comment: It is already corrupted. I also checked my servlet by launching it with 'Run File' in Netbeans. This is what is returned to a browser:`Zaznacz prawid\u0142ow\u0105 operacj\u0119 por\u00f3wnywania dw\u00f3ch zmiennych typu`

Comment: Did you add the unicode escape sequences for better readability here or are they literally contained in the string?

Comment: No, I didn't. I pasted this part directly here.

Comment: Ok, then it was probably the IDE doing it. Otherwise you would see them literally in the output as well. But then the transmission seems to work (I don't know the unicode of your special chars, but they look reasonable). I guess something is wrong with the way you further process the string. Its unlikely that Gson is doing something wrong I would rather look at the later code.